# Javascript: variable from form input comes back from PHP as undefined when form uses class selector instead of

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have no idea what is going on here. I have my form as follows:

```
echo '<form class="changePassForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
echo '<input class = "passwordText" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="passwordText">';
echo '</form>';
```

The form must have the class selector in order for my css below to work (am a bit unclear as to why but I have not found a way around this):

```
.changePassForm {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.passwordText {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.passwordText :hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.passwordText :focus {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  color: #53e3a6;
}
.changePassForm button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #53e3a6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
.changePassForm button:hover {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}
```

Below is the javascript that should pass the input from the form stored in pass to a php file to be echoed. I know this works because the console.log "WORKS!!" is output correctly.

```
$(".passwordText").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        var pass = $('.changePassForm input').val();
        //var pass = document.getElementById("p2");
        $.ajax({
            url: "../php/passwordchange.php", // Url to which the request is send
            type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: 'passwordText=' + pass, // data sent to php file
            success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
            {
                console.log(data);

            }});    
        console.log("WORKS!!");   
    }
});
```

Below is my php that should echo the contents entered in the form:

```
session_start();
include("../php/Session.class.php");
$sess = new Session();
$sess->Init();
$cookie = isset($_COOKIE["session"]); 
if($cookie) 
{
    $cookie = $_COOKIE["session"];
    $account = $sess->Verify($cookie);
}
$pass=$_POST['passwordText']; //name of input
echo $pass;
```

And as it is, pass is echoed as `undefined`. This is troubling because if I change the selector of the form to an id instead of class and store pass as

```
$('#changePassForm input').val();
```

The input text is echoed correctly. What is going wrong here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Using the id selector shouldnt work as your form does not have an id attribute. Does some other element have an id of `changePassForm`?

Comment: Do you have multiple forms with `class="changePassForm"`?

Comment: Why don't you use `$(this).val()`?

Comment: You are outputting "WORKS!!" to the console in the event handler for onkeydown. So it will display "WORKS!!" whether your ajax is successful or not.

Comment: What do you see if you do `console.log(pass)` before the AJAX call?

Comment: You are submitting the form in the traditional sense if Enter is pressed, probably before AJAX is even returning a response. Get rid of `if(event.keyCode == 13){` and it's matching `}` and `return false;` at the end of your Event code, then get back to us.

Comment: There are multiple solutions for this. The easiest probably being to put a `name` or `id` in addition to `class`.